# Sometimes InvalidArgumentError: 'handle' must be a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I installed 'React-google-login' to react project. And I am writing an autotest that should bypass this module.

```
try {
  await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div/button`)), 10000).click();
  await driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(async function(handles){
      await driver.switchTo().window(handles[1])
        .then(async function(){    // ERROR: InvalidArgumentError: invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
          await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('identifierId')),20000).sendKeys('test@gmail.com', Key.ENTER)
          await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name('password')),20000).sendKeys('test1234', Key.ENTER)  // ERROR: ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
      });
  });
  } catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
  }
```

In some cases the code fulfills, in some cases the error is:

```
InvalidArgumentError: invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
```

And in some cases the error is:

```
ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
```

Tell me, please, what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution decides my problem.

```
      try {
         await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
         await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div/button/div`)), 10000)  // wait this element
         await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div/button`)).click();                   // -> after click on it
         let winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();                                             // first window value 
       await driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(async  function(handles){
         await driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(async function(){   
            await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('identifierId')),20000);                    // wait this element
       await driver.findElement(By.id('identifierId')).sendKeys('test@gmail.com',      Key.ENTER)    // after input value
             await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name('password')),20000);                     // wait this element
             await driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys('test1234', Key.ENTER)           // after input value
         });
       });
       driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);                                                    // Change to the first window
       await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div/img`)), 10000)
       /* Any actions */
       } catch (e) {
         console.log(e)        
       }
```